# QR Code ActiveX Control: The Position of the control is different when Printing

Tags: printing, mfc, activex, ondraw, cdc

I had tried to google for many keys like COleControl, IOleInPlaceSite....
But I still have no idea for this.
I know when activex control is inactive,the container won't create window for the activex control!
So the rect will be different to Ondraw!
How do I make the control be the same place?
In ReportViewer I can control the position of the QR Code!
But when I print it to the PDF, it's always on the left top conner of the paper!
Thank for your help!

```
`
void CQRControlCtrl::OnDraw(CDC* pDC, const CRect& rcBounds, const CRect& rcInvalid)
{
    if(*m_DataText == NULL )
        m_DataText = L"";       

    LPWSTR szText = m_DataText.GetBuffer(m_DataText.GetLength());   

    int nSize = m_qSize;
    int nMargin = m_qMargin;

    BOOL bPrinting = pDC->IsPrinting();

    if (!pDC)
        return;

    double PixelsPermmX = (*pDC).GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSX);
    double PixelsPermmY = (*pDC).GetDeviceCaps(LOGPIXELSY);

    pDC->SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC);
    pDC->SetWindowExt(48,48);   
    pDC->SetViewportExt(PixelsPermmX,PixelsPermmY); 

    HBITMAP hbitmap = GetHBitmapW(szText, nMargin, nSize, QR_ECLEVEL_M);    

    CBitmap *pBitmap=CBitmap::FromHandle(hbitmap);
    BITMAP bitmap;
    GetObject(hbitmap,sizeof(BITMAP),&bitmap);

    int nHeight = bitmap.bmHeight;
    int nWidth = bitmap.bmWidth;

    CRect rect;
    this->GetRectInContainer(rect);

    CDC MemDC;      
    MemDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);  
    MemDC.SelectObject(pBitmap);    

    pDC->StretchBlt(rect.left,rect.top,nWidth,nHeight,&MemDC,0,0,nWidth,nHeight,SRCCOPY);
}`
```